# Почему метод "message.get()" не работает?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, методы, бот

**Вопросы:**

- Почему метод `message.get()` не работает? Что использовать вместо него?
- Как получить историю сообщений от пользователя или беседы, ранее писавшие боту?
- Почему  `messages.getConversations()` возвращает только последнее сообщение?

**Предыстория:**

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с `VK API` на Python'е 3. Сделал простого бота по инструкциям (видео на YouTube, статьи различные и т.д.).

На следующий день, бот перестал работать. Происходила ошибка с параметрами метода  `message.get()` (Ошибка №100). Зашел на документацию ВК, стал искать ошибку. Увидел, что метод устарел и понял, что метод лучше не использовать (даже если ошибка не в нем), но не знал что делать.

На просторах Интернета нашел видео, в котором использовался метод `messages.getConversations()`, но он  показался мне менее гибким, т.к. он возвращает информацию о диалогах бота и только последнее сообщение диалога (а предыдуший возвращал список диалогов в месте с сообщениями).

Хештеги: (Написал для поиска по словам)

```
vk
vk-api
vkontakte
vkontakte-api
вк
вконтакте
метод message.get
метод messages.getConversations
ошибка 100
параметры
бот
чат-бот
бот для вк
чат-бот для вк
python
python 3
python.3-x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `message.get` устарел и возможно был заблокирован (а если ещё нет, все равно в не рекомендуется использовать).  Вместо него лучше использовать сочетание методов `messages.getConversations` и `messages.getHistory`. 1 метод возвращает список диалогов(можно использовать фильтры), 2 возвращает сообщения диалога по его id. Для наглядности выполним следующий код:

```
VK = vk_api.VkApi(token = ТОКЕН_ДОСТУПА) # ТОКЕН_ДОСТУПА = 'ae4919g789965bf10...'  -- токен доступа к сообществу 
print(VK.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter":'unanswered'}))  #Метод, который собирает новые диалоги с неотвеченными сообщениями
```

Результат (привел в читабельный вид):

```
{
    'count': 1, 
    'items': [{

         'conversation': {  

                'unanswered': True, 
                'peer': {
                        'local_id': *айди собеседника или беседы*, 
                        'type': 'user', 
                        'id': *ID собеседника*, 
                        }
                'last_message_id': 312, 
                'in_read': 312, 
                'out_read': 312, 
                'can_write': {'allowed': True}

                            }, 

        'last_message': {

                'is_hidden': False, 
                'id': 312, 
                'conversation_message_id': 312,
                'from_id': *айди автора последнего сообщения*,
                'date': 1531127807, 
                'important': False, 
                'attachments': [], 
                'text': *Текст последнего сообщения*, 
                'out': 0, 
                'peer_id': *айди диалога*,  
                'random_id': 0,
                'fwd_messages': []
                            }
                }]
}
```

На самом деле, метод `messages.getConversations` дает достаточно много, помимо последнего сообщения.

В нашем случае  нам нужен параметр `'peer_id'` -- ID диалога. Кстати, хотел сказать, что в примере только 1 диалог, но их может быть и больше. По этому, мы будем постоянно пользоваться циклом `for` чтобы последовательно отвечать на сообщения разных диалогов.  Теперь вместе с этим методом используем  `messages.getHistory`:

```
VK = vk_api.VkApi(token = ТОКЕН_ДОСТУПА)
Диалоги_Бота = VK.method("messages.getConversations", {"offset": 0, "count": 20, "filter":'unanswered'})
for Данные_о_диалоге in Диалоги_Бота['items']:
    ID_Диалога = Данные_о_диалоге['conversation']['peer']['local_id']
    print(VK.method('messages.getHistory', {'peer_id': ID_Диалога,'count': 5, }))
```

И вот мы вывели на экран списки сообщений из каждого диалога. Далее, вместо того, чтобы выводить сообщения в консоль мы можем отвечать на них, удалять их, пересылать, записывать и т.д. 
Таким образом мы смогли заменить старый метод сочетанием 2-х новых.